# Read Excel file and store it in mysql database using NPOI library

Tags: asp.net-core, oop, npoi, xssf, exceldatareader

Here I'm trying to read Excel file and insert data into mysql database using NPOI library. Sometimes it works perfectly sometimes it misses some data, it shows Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What am I doing wrong? Help me..

```
using ExcelRead.Data;

using ExcelRead.Models;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;

using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;

using System.Diagnostics;

using System.IO;

namespace ExcelRead.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Excl()
        {
           
            String filePath = @"C:\Users\zameer.ahammad\Documents\TimeCards\FieldGlass\timeSheet.supplier.list.xlsx";
            try
            {
                
                IWorkbook workbook = null;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
                ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheet("timeSheet.supplier.list");
                if (sheet != null)
                {
                    int rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum+1;
                    for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)   //First two rows of excel data is not required
                    {
                        fieldglassTimesheetDataModel excelinsert = new fieldglassTimesheetDataModel();
                        IRow curRow = sheet.GetRow(i);

                        excelinsert.ID = curRow.GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim();
                        excelinsert.Worker = curRow.GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim();
                        excelinsert.ST = (float)curRow.GetCell(6).NumericCellValue;
                        excelinsert.OT = (float)curRow.GetCell(7).NumericCellValue;
                        excelinsert.DT = (float)curRow.GetCell(8).NumericCellValue;

                        
                        //Console.WriteLine(cellVal0 + "\t\t" + cellVal1 + "\t\t" + cellVal2 + "\t\t" + cellVal3 + "\t\t" + cellVal4);
                        _context.Add(excelinsert);
                        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        //excelinsert = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);

            }
            return View("Index");
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the wrong libraries. EF is an ORM, not an ETL tool. There are no objects involved here. NPOI is mainly a tool for creating Excel documents, not a tool for reading data like the `ExcelDataReader` library you tagged.

Comment: You can use [MySqlBulkCopy](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/) with ExcelDataReader to read an Excel file and send the data directly to MySQL. You can specify source to target mappings through the `ColumnMappings` collection, either as names or column indexes